# How to attach canvas image using ContactForm7

Tags: wordpress, image, html5-canvas, contact-form-7

I created an HTML canvas where a user can sketch a floor plan out.

**Currently the user has to**

- Fill out a form (https://www.xmfg.com/cubes/request-for-quote/)
- Click on a link to get to the canvas so they can do a quick sketch (Prototype:http://www.xmfg.com/cubefloorplan/)
- Save the image
- Go back to the form to attach the image
- Submit the form

**I want to make it easier and I don't know if this is possible or not using Wordpress' ContactForm7 plugin.**

Is there a way to make it so that after the user draws on the canvas, they can click a button that will create the image and have it automatically attach to the form vs having to save image and then browse to look for the image?

Comment: I hate linking to plugins, but would this work? https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-signature-addon/faq/

Comment: @Spartacus that is interesting. So instead of using HTML5 canvas, use that. I'd have to look into it to see if you can do more than just sign.

Comment: You should be able to draw anything you want, and if you label the field properly, they'd never know it was meant for a signature.

Comment: @Spartacus nice! Thanks!